# U-Net segmentation without having mask

Tags: deep-learning, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation, medical-imaging

I am new to deep learning and Semantic segmentation.

I have a dataset of medical images (CT) in Dicom format, in which I need to segment tumours and organs involved from the images. I have labelled organs contoured by our physician which we call it RT structure stored in Dicom format also.

As far as I know, people usually use "mask". Does it mean I need to convert all the contoured structure in the rt structure to mask? or I can use the information from the RT structure (.dcm) directly as my input?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In general, `If you create a mask` you can train it easily with deep learning model (Unet). Other wise if you don't want to crate mask, you need to `create a custom data generator` & it will little bit complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a special library called `pydicom` that you need to install before you can actually decode and later visualise the X-ray image.

Now, since you want to apply semantic segmentation and you want to segment the tumours, the solution to this is to create a neural network which accepts as input a pair of `[image,mask]`, where, say, all the locations in the mask are 0 except for the zones where the tumour is, which are marked with 1; practically your ground truth is the mask.

Of course for this you will have to implement your `CustomDataGenerator()` which must yield at every step a batch of `[image,mask]` pairs as stated above.